# Displaying dynamically changing values by the sides of thumbs in two thumb seek bar

Tags: android, seekbar

I was searching for two thumb seek bar that could be used for price filter design,when I came across this code....Everything is fine except that we cannot dynamically get the values set by dragging the thumbs....say in textview...
this is the link for android code of two thumb seek bar https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/issues/detail?id=22 and this is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar_container);
    RangeSeekBar<Integer> mRangeSeekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(0, 100,
            this);
    mRelativeLayout.addView(mRangeSeekBar);
}
}
```

Help will be very much appreciated ...Thanks in advance...Veronica